# How many bots have JS "enabled"?

Tags: javascript, spam-prevention, bots

We're talking your average everyday spamming bots -- those which we try to protect against using captcha.

**How many of them are capable of running JS in some kind of embedded-browser?**

If it's a very tiny amount, then how on earth can solutions like this be useful: http://wcaptcha.wozia.pt/sample.php

Apart from the obvious usability/accessibility issues, these drag-n-drop solutions require the client to have JS. There's not even a fallback. So, assuming it is intended to protect against bots (non-humans) isn't it entirely redundant, or at least redundant to the extent of how many bots would be technically capable of attempting such a thing?

If the client has JS (*which is a pre-requisite for this solution to work*) then isn't it safe (within reasonable measure) to assume the client not a bot?

Comment: Seeing that the solution to the quest is in the name of the image (e.g. 'drag the lock' -> the image is called 'lock.png') and any element that is not the right one cannot be dragged on the circle at all, it does not seem that effective. But

Comment: It seems funnier than typing inscrutable and unreadable words from an image, but I don't think it's more effective than captcha. I don't know an answer to your question, but I'm almost completely sure clients will always have JS enabled. It's kind of impossible to have it disabled these days.

Comment: People who have it disabled are either testing stuff, or they're paranoid. Either way they're the lowest possible conversion rate client. Don't waste your time on them.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't that redundant. If you just detect for Javascript, people can still boot up instances of Selenium and pretend to comment. The number of spam bots doing that now is in the minority, but as the spam wars evolve, you can bet spam bots will move on to other methods such as using a browser. If you detect for Javascript AND make them drag and drop something, it'll definitely prove you're a human.

But I think this implementation is just not practical because there is still a % of people that have JS off for whatever reason. I hear this % is 2 or 3%, which is still a good amount when you're talking about hundreds of thousands of visitors.

An alternative is to have a noscript option that asks the user to activate Javascript if he/she wants to comment on the blog.

Comment: +1 for that last bit about javascript being required for commenting.

Comment: The % of people with JS disabled are a minority not worth catering for. They are geeks with an extremely low likelihood of conversion. You could just as easily spend your time on people using IE7. Anyone with a brain doesn't use it and doesn't cater to it. Stop wasting your time on outdated tech.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, very few spambots will have JavaScript enabled.

Spam is a percentages game. Only a very small percentage of spam messages will trigger any revenue for the spammer. If you can increase the cost of spam, you make it economically infeasible. Spamming in a JavaScript-enabled browser is *way* more expensive than spamming on the command line, so you can send out *more* spam at a time if you stick to curl.

Yes, it is redundant.

Rather than making users do this pointless task, you might as well automatically perform a javascript check. It could be as simple as a script that grabs the domain name of the site and inserts it into each form as a hidden field. This will stop all drive-by spammers. If your site is high-profile enough to attract custom spammers, this solution won't be enough anyway.

For those without JavaScript, just show them a regular old image CAPTCHA after their post fails.

Answer (score 0):

A bigger issue is usability IMHO. Captcha is always going to decrease conversion rates, and often significantly. If your goal is to use JS as a means of deterring bots, I can tell you that it has significantly reduced bot traffic for me by more than 90%.

Just incorporate a hidden field that gets populated by JS. If it isn't filled in, they're either a bot, or one of those idiots with JS turned off, who you don't really want to cater to anyway.

Also incorporate a hidden field that is visible in the DOM. Make it fly off the screen with CSS like "position:absolute; left:9999px; top: -9999px". Don't use "display:none;" If this field is filled in, they're a bot.

I cut down our spam more than 90% with this, so you should use it over Captcha types, unless you're a big business. If you're a big business, your only real solution is a back-end server side solution. Good luck finding that on StackOverflow. They'll close your comment quicker than people can answer it. (and it will have better Google rank than anything out there)